# SQL Query: Filling Blank/Null values with other values in column1 based on values in column 2

Tags: sql

I need a help with SQL query. I have a table with some of the values missing in column. I want to fill the missing values based on the value of column1

```
-----Col_1-------Col_2------
    12345         Value 1
    12345         
    12345
    54321         Value 2
    54321         
    54321         
------------------------------
```

Output should be like this.

```
-----Col_1-------Col_2------
    12345         Value 1
    12345         Value 1
    12345         Value 1
    54321         Value 2
    54321         Value 2
    54321         Value 2
------------------------------
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Maybe you want to describe the logic you want in plain English. LIke 'if the value of col1 is 123 then Col2 should be 'Value 456'. Or 'if I find one value on col2 I should copy it to any other places where col1 is the. same but empty. Have you tried the SQL UPDATE command to see how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
CASE 
   WHEN x IS NULL 
   THEN ( SELECT y from a WHERE y = y AND y IS NOT NULL)
   ELSE x
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select col_1, max(col_2) over (partition by col_1)
from t;
```

This assigns the same value to all rows with a given `col_1`.  If you want to keep existing values, even if they don't match:

```
select col_1, coalesce(col_2, max(col_2) over (partition by col_1))
from t;
```

If you wanted to update the values:

```
update t
    set col_2 = (select t2.col2 from t t2 where t.col_1 = t2.col_1 and t2.col_2 is not null fetch first 1 row only)
    where col_2 is null;
```